# How can I find my Oracle 10g server version?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I don't have physical access to my Oracle server but I can run some sql command from Toad. Is there a way I can find wich version the server is running, like 10.2.3.1. I know it's 10g but I'd like to know wich patchs and maybe more (memory used, buffers, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
```

More here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dynamic_performance_views.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition, to the accepted answer, you can find out the patches that have been applied by querying the registry$history table:

```
select id,action,comments from registry$history;
```

This table is normally only visible to the SYS user.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from product_component_version;
```

will return:

[image]